# Initialize Class in Java

Tags: java, android, objective-c

What is analog in Java for first initialization like?

This is a code in Objective-C:

```
@implementation DataClass
    + (void)initialize {
     if (self == [DataClass class]) {

         }
     }
    @end
```

More detailed:

Usual constructor in Obj-C is:

```
- (id)init {

    return [super init];
}
```

analog of it in Java is:

```
public DataClass
{}
```

I do not want to use usual object constructor. I need Class-first-touch function.

Comment: Shouldn't it be if (self != nil) ?

Comment: No, but it doesn't mean. I wanna to convert code in Objective-C to Java. I don't know how to change this part of code.

Comment: @trololo, well, when it is about a 1:1 conversion, then my suggestion below should help. But there is still a difference. In Obj-C `initialize` is called once for every class when an object is instantiated for the first time. But without calling `[super initialize]` (which you can do but shouldn't) it is called for each of the superclasses automatically. In Java you will have to care for that yourself when you use the constructors for that purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
class Foo {
    static List<Character> abc;
    static {
        abc = new LinkedList<Character>();
        for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; ++c) {
            abc.add( c );
        }
    }
}
```

This way gives the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

java and objective-c are different. 
O-c its like c++ when in one file you are declare the class and in another file you are declare the implementation 
but in java both are in the same place, and you cannot make them in two files to implement a class.